# Is it bad practice to dynamically update the schema in a-frame? If not, can this be reflected in the inspector?

Tags: javascript, aframe, webvr

I am creating geometries in a-frame and I would like to be able to tweak the vertices via the inspector or through html attributes.

Since some of these shapes have many vec3s (and I would also like to be able to pass them in dynamically) I do not necessarily want to write them all into the schema manually.

Is it ok (I mean recommended practice) to update the schema dynamically from within the component? I have done this and it works fine, the only problem being that this is not reflected in the inspector.

Is this a good idea or is there a better way to achieve this? If this is ok, how can I get these schema items to appear in the inspector?

Please find example code below (NB in this example my vertices are a simple set and already available in the code but this is just to demonstrate the principle, they would normally be a much larger set)

Example component

```
//component that updates its own schema
AFRAME.registerComponent('schema_query', {

    schema: {

    },

    init: function(){
        var verts = [{"x":0,"y":0,"z":0},{"x":0,"y":5,"z":0},{"x":5,"y":0,"z":0}]
        for (i = 0; i < verts.length; i++){
            this.data["vertices_"+i] = {type: "vec3", default: {x: verts[i].x, y: verts[i].y, z: verts[i].z,}}
        }
        console.log(this.data)
    },

});
```

HTML

```
<a-entity
    schema_query>
</a-entity>
```

Result is the following in the console (as I would expect)

```
{vertices_0: {…}, vertices_1: {…}, vertices_2: {…}}
//etc.
```

Thanks as ever for any advice

Comment: This is too incomplete to be an answer, but dynamic schemas that show in the inspector are possible, as some core components to this (e.g. geometry). See https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/core/component.html#definition_lifecycle_handler_methods_updateschema

Comment: Thanks W. Murphy, yes I looked up the geometry code, I have posted a working example below based on those investigations. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks very much to everyone for your pointers, I have a solution based on your comments for anyone who is interested. Please see below how I add vec3s into the schema dynamically in updateSchema, these are then available throughout the component via `this.data` and crucially, they are visible in the inspector! (see image below)

The component;

```
//component that updates its own schema
AFRAME.registerComponent('schema_query_update', {

    schema: {

    },

    init: function(){
        console.log(this.data)
        //logs the new vec3s
    },

    updateSchema: function (data) {
        var tempSchema = {}
        var verts = [{x:0,y:0,z:0},{x:0,y:5,z:0},{x:5,y:0,z:0}]
        for (i = 0; i < verts.length; i++){
            tempSchema["vertices_"+i] = {type: 'vec3', default: {x: verts[i].x, y: verts[i].y, z: verts[i].z}};
        }
        this.extendSchema(tempSchema);
    }

});
```

Attached;

```
<a-entity
    schema_query_update>
</a-entity>
```

And there they are!;

[image: dynamically added schema items visible and editable in the inspector]

PS I realise that putting an array within the updateSchema is probably not a great idea, its just a simple way of showing it working

Thanks again all

Answer (score 0):

You could define a custom schema property for the list of vec3s, and then use a parse function to parse it into a list in the component.

In theory that would allow the inspector to register it, although I'm not sure how it handles custom properties:

https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/core/component.html#custom-property-type

```
schema: {
    // Parse slash-delimited string to an array (e.g., `foo="myProperty: a/b"` to `['a', 'b']`).
    myProperty: {
        default: [],
        parse: function (value) {
            return value.split('/');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Noam, yeah I have tried doing that with some ok results but it always ends up being very unweildy and hard to manage at both ends. I just wondered if this might be a neater way as it piggy backs on the existing good features of the library. I’m also just curious whether this has been done before, if it’s a good idea or not. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I'll add that modifying the schema at runtime is OK, too. I _usually_ try to avoid it for simplicity, but even some of the core A-Frame components (`material`, `geometry`) do so.

Comment: Don thanks for the examples in core. Agree, it's a bit of a pain to parse the attribute when you can just do it in the init function. Nick best of luck with the project!